# How to get the header from table in protractor?

Tags: protractor

I have table in my angular application. How to iterate through the table headers and compare the headings in it?

Following is sample html code.

---

```
<table>
        <tbody> 
             <th>
                <td>head1</td>
                <td>head2</td>
                <td>head2</td>
            </th>

            <tr>
                <td>row1Col1</td>
                <td>row1Col2</td>
                <td>row1Col3</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>row2Col1</td>
                <td>row3Col2</td>
                <td>row4Col3</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>row3Col1</td>
                <td>row3Col2</td>
                <td>row3Col3</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

How to loop through the number of columns(headers).

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**

```
var expectHeaders = ['head1', 'head2', 'head3'];
var headers = element.all(by.css('table > tbody > th > td'));

expect(headers.getText()).toEqual(expectHeaders);

//or do assertion in then()
headers.getText().then(function(actualHeaders){
  expect(actualHeaders).toEqual(expectHeaders);
  // or compare header one by one in loop
  expectHeaders.forEach(function(expectHeader, index){
     expect(actualHeaders[index]).toEqual(expectHeader);
  })
})
```

**Method 2**
    if you prefer to iterate through each header

```
var expectedHeaders = ['head1', 'head2', 'head3'];
var headers = element.all(by.css('table > tbody > th > td'));

expectedHeaders.forEach(function(header, index){
   expect(headers.get(index).getText()).toEqual(header);
   // or compare in then()
   headers.get(index).getText().then(function(actual){
      expect(actual).toEqual(header)
   })
});
```

Comment: Thanks yong!!..I have a question. What if one more column added in future to the table.I am searching for iterate through the total number column(loop should depend on number of column)

Comment: If the header changed in future, you have to change the expected value in assertion statement in test script.  Like `expect(headers).toEqual(['head1', 'head2', 'head3', 'head4', ...]);` .  I can't get the reason why you need to iterate through each head by index.

Comment: Is there any way using then function?